# ACT (green) light blinks 7 times on startup

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I use PINN to dual-boot between the 32 bit and 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS. When I boot to the 64 bit version PINN exits and the screen blanks, but then the ACT light repeatedly flashes slowly 7 times. When I boot to the 32 bit version it starts up fine. Is this problem SD card corruption or a different problem?

Update: I re-copied the /boot files and it boots, but now my mouse and keyboard don't work. What's wrong now?

Comment: Have you read the 'not booting' sticky on the RPF forum? Especially the Pi4 section at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: The thing is that the system boots, but not the OS. Also see my update above

Comment: You should ask the PINN developer/maintainer at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=142574

Comment: I reinstalled and it works now. Unfortunately sudo doesn't work after reinstalling! I can't win!

Comment: Please create an answer for your solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again, anoing us for years.

Comment: It wasn't answered until just now, I went to do just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the Raspberry Pi OS and it worked, I don't even know why it stopped working in the first place